# Need to display the WebCrawler output in the form of tree-like structure

Tags: java, jsoup

I have below code to fetch the pages inside the given URL but I am not sure how to display them in tree like structure.

public class BasicWebCrawler {

```
private HashSet<String> links;

public BasicWebCrawler() {
    links = new HashSet<String>();
}

public void getPageLinks(String URL) {
    //4. Check if you have already crawled the URLs 
    //(we are intentionally not checking for duplicate content in this example)
    if (!links.contains(URL)) {
        try {
            //4. (i) If not add it to the index
            if (links.add(URL)) {
                System.out.println(URL);
            }

            //2. Fetch the HTML code
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            //3. Parse the HTML to extract links to other URLs
            Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a[href^=\"" +URL+ "\"]");

            //5. For each extracted URL... go back to Step 4.
            for (Element page : linksOnPage) {
                getPageLinks(page.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("For '" + URL + "': " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //1. Pick a URL from the frontier
    new BasicWebCrawler().getPageLinks("https://www.wikipedia.com/");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I managed to do what you asked, when all links on site are checked or site has no links then the recursion will finish, but in internet it's actually not doable, it's funny where can you go from one site just by clicking first not checked link:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class BasicWebCrawler {

    private HashSet<String> links;

    public BasicWebCrawler() {
        links = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void getPageLinks(String URL, int level) {
        //4. Check if you have already crawled the URLs
        //(we are intentionally not checking for duplicate content in this example)
        if (!links.contains(URL)) {
            try {

                //4. (i) If not add it to the index
                if (links.add(URL)) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                        System.out.print("-");
                    }
                    System.out.println(URL);
                }

                //2. Fetch the HTML code
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                //3. Parse the HTML to extract links to other URLs
                Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a[href]");

                //5. For each extracted URL... go back to Step 4.
                for (Element page : linksOnPage) {
                    getPageLinks(page.attr("abs:href"), level + 1);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("For '" + URL + "': " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1. Pick a URL from the frontier
        new BasicWebCrawler().getPageLinks("http://mysmallwebpage.com/", 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting all the links which are inside the parent URL and that's what expected. But I just want to format it in a tree-like structure as I have mentioned in the above sample example.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand what do you mean by forming it in tree-like structure?  Do you want to print it like tree or to store it in tree?

Comment: I want to print it more of a king of yaml format. Please refer below e.g    www.xyz.com/abc/uuu
www.xyz.com/abc/yee
www.xyz.com/qtw/rid


Print in format:-
www.xyz.com/
-abc
 -uuu
 -yee
-qtw
 -rid